# devnagari font integration in PDF

Tags: c, pdf

i am facing problem on writing devnagari font on PDF the output is not coming i have downloaded the ttf file
my code

problem code

```
  fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  fprintf(file, "40 100 TD\n");
  fprintf(file, "/NotoSansDevanagari-VariableFont_wdth,wght 17 Tf\n");
  fprintf(file, "(Result pdf created on : २०८० साउन ३, बुधवार) Tj\n");
  fprintf(file, "ET\n");
```

full code

```
// For refernce the initial PDF syntax code is given in README.mdd
// https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js-sample-files/blob/7dbc3700be83936e32d8df04dbb2df8024f38b59/helloworld.pdf
//MY TEST PROJECT
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 // #include<conio.h>

int pdf(char name[], char school[], int, int);

int pdf(char name[], char school[], int score, int numberOfQuestions) {
  int content_length = strlen(name) + strlen(school);
  float page_width = 595.276, page_height = 841.890;
  FILE * file;

  file = fopen("result.pdf", "wb");
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file.");
    return 1;
  }

  fprintf(file, "%%PDF-1.7\n");

  fprintf(file, "1 0 obj\n");
  fprintf(file, "<<\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Type /Catalog\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Pages 2 0 R\n");
  fprintf(file, ">>\n");
  fprintf(file, "endobj\n");

  fprintf(file, "2 0 obj\n");
  fprintf(file, "<<\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Type /Pages\n");

  // page format
  fprintf(file, "  /MediaBox [ 0 0 %f %f ]\n", page_width, page_height);

  fprintf(file, "  /Count 1\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Kids [ 3 0 R ]\n");
  fprintf(file, ">>\n");
  fprintf(file, "endobj\n");

  fprintf(file, "3 0 obj\n");
  fprintf(file, "<<\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Type /Page\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Parent 2 0 R\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Resources <<\n");
  fprintf(file, "    /Font <<\n");
  fprintf(file, "      /F1 4 0 R\n");
  fprintf(file, "    >>\n");
  fprintf(file, "  >>\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Contents 5 0 R\n");
  fprintf(file, ">>\n");
  fprintf(file, "endobj\n");

  fprintf(file, "4 0 obj\n");
  fprintf(file, "<<\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Type /Font\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Subtype /Type1\n");

  // Font name
  fprintf(file, "  /BaseFont /Helvetica\n");

  fprintf(file, ">>\n");
  fprintf(file, "endobj\n");

  fprintf(file, "5 0 obj\n");
  fprintf(file, "<<\n");
  // Text length
  fprintf(file, "  /Length %d\n", content_length);
  fprintf(file, ">>\n");
  fprintf(file, "stream\n");
  // New Text object
  //******************************************************************************
  fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  fprintf(file, "80 791 TD\n");
  fprintf(file, "/F1 30 Tf\n");
  fprintf(file, "(EXAMIFY-made by  833) Tj\n");
  fprintf(file, "ET\n");
  //************************SCHOOL_PART************************************************
  fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  fprintf(file, "40 731 TD\n");
  fprintf(file, "/F1 12 Tf\n");
  fprintf(file, "(%s) Tj\n", school);
  fprintf(file, "ET\n");
  // New Text object
  //************************NAME_PART************************************************
  fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  fprintf(file, "/F1 12 Tf\n");
  fprintf(file, "40 700 TD\n");
  fprintf(file, "(Mr. %s..) Tj\n", name);
  fprintf(file, "ET\n");
  //**************************SCORES******************************************************
  fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  fprintf(file, "/F1 12 Tf\n");
  fprintf(file, "40 670 TD\n");
  fprintf(file, "(The Score %d..) Tj\n", score);
  fprintf(file, "ET\n");
  //**************************numberofQuestions******************************************************
  fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  fprintf(file, "/F1 12 Tf\n");
  fprintf(file, "40 640 TD\n");
  fprintf(file, "(Number of Questions %d..) Tj\n", numberOfQuestions);
  fprintf(file, "ET\n");
  //**************************8888888******************************************************

  // fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  // fprintf(file, "40 100 TD\n");
  // fprintf(file, "/F1 17 Tf\n");
  // fprintf(file, "(SAM_TIME101-2080-4-4 v1.01) Tj\n");
  fprintf(file, "BT\n");
  fprintf(file, "40 100 TD\n");
  fprintf(file, "/NotoSansDevanagari-VariableFont_wdth,wght 17 Tf\n");
  fprintf(file, "(Result pdf created on : २०८० साउन ३, बुधवार) Tj\n");
  fprintf(file, "ET\n");

  fprintf(file, "ET\n");
  fprintf(file, "endstream\n");
  fprintf(file, "endobj\n");
  fprintf(file, "xref\n");
  fprintf(file, "0 6\n");
  fprintf(file, "0000000000 65535 f\n");
  fprintf(file, "0000000010 00000 n\n");
  fprintf(file, "0000000079 00000 n\n");
  fprintf(file, "0000000173 00000 n\n");
  fprintf(file, "0000000301 00000 n\n");
  fprintf(file, "0000000380 00000 n\n");
  fprintf(file, "trailer\n");
  fprintf(file, "<<\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Size 6\n");
  fprintf(file, "  /Root 1 0 R\n");
  fprintf(file, ">>\n");
  fprintf(file, "startxref\n");
  fprintf(file, "492\n");
  fprintf(file, "%%EOF\n");

  fclose(file);
  printf("THANK YOU FILE CREATED \n");
  printf("Check result.pdf in current directory \n");
  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

my output

```
Result pdf created on : à¥¨à¥¦à¥®à¥¦ à¤¸à¤¾à¤‰à¤¨ à¥©, à¤¬à¥•à¤§à¤μ
```

i have `NotoSansDevanagari-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf` fonts and i am unable , this is my ptoject i am working i am learning to code so please help me it will mean a lot thanks
the output is not coming as expected and i am facing errors on the output

Comment: First of all, hand-coding PDFs to a certain degree works for very simple PDFs but usually becomes too complicated as soon as you try something that is not that simple. Use of non-latin glyphs usually is _not simple_. Thus, you should look for a good PDF library with proper support of non-latin glyphs and use that instead of hand-coding the PDF. Furthermore, if you try to hand-code a PDF, study the PDF specification first. A somewhat strict PDF viewer wouldn't have shown the output you posted but instead would have rejected your file as completely broken.

Comment: please can u recommend

Comment: *"please can u recommend"* - Unfortunately no. I'm usually processing PDFs in Java or C#, not in C, so I don't know which PDF library for C has the needed features...

Comment: PDF-1.7 can support UTF-16BE encoded strings if they begin with a UTF-16BE encoded byte order mark (U+FEFF) character (bytes 254, 255). PDF-2.0 can also support UTF-8 encoded strings if they begin with a UTF-8 encoded byte order mark character (bytes 239, 187, 191).

Comment: Strings in PDF page content streams are not PDF strings, though. Their encoding depends upon the font in use.

Comment: @IanAbbott *"PDF-1.7 can support UTF-16BE encoded strings..."* - as John just said, the encoding of strings in content streams and strings at COS level is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

When you start writing images and fonts in a plain text PDF it starts getting highly complex, as there are many ways and limitations to consider.

Simple Latin non UTF-8 text is provided without needing fonts, just the codes for the 14 old "standard fonts". But once characters go outside that range, then you start at the deep end,  with font sub-setting thus CID and CMAP.

There are ways around that complexity by templating the characters you need in a custom CID based font, but for a full alphabet it's hard to maintain.

[image]

The page data stream goes something like this example with 2 Fonts starting at 40 100. First font /F0 is 12 point and second /F1 is 17 just to be more obvious. This is a fast sketch, based on your source desire.

```
4 0 obj
<</Length 663>>
stream
q
/GS0 gs
1 0 0 1 40 100 cm
0 0 0 rg
BT
/F0 12 Tf
1 0 0 1 0 -28.08 Tm
[<017500110091009600910016008300900095000700870098008300900083008900830094008B015E001900830094008B00830084008E>-10.000002<00870009009100900096024F009900860096008A015900990089008A0096>1<00030268026E000300170088>] TJ
1 0 0 1 0 -49.3273 Tm
[<0015>1<008700950097008E00960003009200860088000300850094008700830096008700860003009100900003015B0003>] TJ
/F1 17 Tf
1 0 0 1 158.4 -49.3273 Tm
[<0359>1<0357035F>-11<03570003>-6.000001<011D012D00EA>-5<010B>7<0003>-6.000001<035A007E0003>-7<010F>34<0132>-39.000005<010A>-7<0119012D0113>] TJ
0 g
/F0 12.0000 Tf
1 0 0 1 305.48548 -49.3273 Tm
<0003> Tj
ET
Q
q
Q

endstream
endobj
```

Now the real problem is "how do those" `<####>` 16 bit double bytes translate into graphics and that is where the 2 small binary fonts need importing.

First we set their metadata

```
6 0 obj
<</BaseFont/CIDFont+F1/DescendantFonts[<</BaseFont/CIDFont+F1/CIDSystemInfo<</Ordering 8 0 R/Registry 9 0 R/Supplement 0>>/CIDToGIDMap/Identity/FontDescriptor<</Ascent 919/CapHeight 638/Descent -250/Flags 6/FontBBox 10 0 R/FontFile2 11 0 R/FontName/CIDFont+F1/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 12 0 R/Type/FontDescriptor>>/Subtype/CIDFontType2/Type/Font/W 13 0 R>>]/Encoding/Identity-H/Subtype/Type0/ToUnicode 14 0 R/Type/Font>>
endobj

7 0 obj
<</BaseFont/CIDFont+F2/DescendantFonts[<</BaseFont/CIDFont+F2/CIDSystemInfo<</Ordering 15 0 R/Registry 16 0 R/Supplement 0>>/CIDToGIDMap/Identity/FontDescriptor<</Ascent 1079/CapHeight 700/Descent -250/Flags 6/FontBBox 17 0 R/FontFile2 18 0 R/FontName/CIDFont+F2/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 19 0 R/Type/FontDescriptor>>/Subtype/CIDFontType2/Type/Font/W 20 0 R>>]/Encoding/Identity-H/Subtype/Type0/ToUnicode 21 0 R/Type/Font>>
endobj
```

Now I can not show all of the file (it is too big). However the 2 generated compressed fonts will start something like this 45 KB one (the cursive one has much fewer entries but as curves tends to be much bigger 113 KB) :-

```
11 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 45071/Length1 99076/Type/Stream>>
stream
xœì½    xTEÖ7^uïí½;ÝtÒ4I:éì{Ò„ ¤³ÂšdI    Í¢l²8€ˆ`œ¨ˆ2 (È8è¨°`ÜFD—AtœFÑaÔqÔ#[º¿SU·’N —yß÷{¾÷ÿü;üî9·nUÝS§N:U÷^E!dƒ„Ü¥5cFßuohBïB(òàèÒQeG/¡¯ÞBH¼cteEþ‰
```

I won't bother showing its 39 characters ToUnicode mapping since you're asking about a  UTF-8 equivalency. So here is the Map for those 16 characters.

```
21 0 obj
<</Length 549>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 12 dict begin begincmap /CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def /CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def /CMapType 2 def 1 begincodespacerange <0000> <FFFF> endcodespacerange 16 beginbfchar <0003> <0020> <007E> <002C> <0088> <0029> <00EA> <0909> <010A> <0927> <010B> <0928> <010F> <092C> <0113> <0930> <0119> <0935> <011D> <0938> <012D> <093E> <0132> <0941> <0357> <0966> <0359> <0968> <035A> <0969> <035F> <096E> endbfchar endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end 
endstream
endobj
```

so common to many
<0003> <0020> is the space bar so let's pick on another

<00EA> <0909> Ah that's like U+0909 the Unicode hex Devanagari Letter U. so graphically `उ`,

and so on and so forth from fourth

[image]

Thus the key is "knowing" what codes need binary placing in the page to be later encoded into BOTH "Unicode" for extraction AND "Graphics" (glyphs) display, and unfortunately in many scripts those may overlap in opposing directions.